# Kitchen Appliance Replacement resistor

Tags: resistors, appliances

I am trying to fix an old Kenwood Chef kitchen mixer that's motor is only working very intermittently. I opened up the unit and found that one of the power resistors are cracked - that is likely causing continuous conductivity issues:
[image: Circuit photo]
A few months ago the appliance spewed a massive amount of white smoke, which I attribute to the popped paper cap on the bottom right, but it continued to function fine until recently. I am planning to replace that as well in any case.

My question is actually whether that cracked resistor is:
 - 56 Ohm (10%) resistor?
 - 90 MegaOhm (.5%) resistor?
 - Something else?

The colour codes look to be [**White**;Black;Blue;Green] (90 MOhm) rather than [Green;Blue;Black;**Silver**] (56 Ohm), but I am really struggling to find 90 MOhm 1-2W resistors on the market.

Comment: It is 56 ohms. For axial-lead resistors, the color band that is closest to the end of the resistor is usually the first one. The exceptions have a more complicated pattern.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @CharlesCowie, the fact that 56Ohm resistors are so much more common made me reconsider my initial determination that it was 90M.
I have been waiting more than 2 weeks for my replacement parts to arrive from Europe here in South Africa, and just noticed that I had accidentally ordered 100mOhm resistors in any case. That prompted me to reconsider the value ;D

Comment: Replace ALL caps. These things are prone to popping with age.

Comment: You may need to check/clean or even replace the brushes. Spares should be available.